# How to setup Ceph radosgw to support multi-tenancy?

Tags: ceph

What are the best options to setup the Ceph radosgw so it supports separate/independent "tenants"? What I'm after:

1. Ensure isolation between tenants, ie: no overlap/conflict in bucket namespace; something separate radosgw "users" doesn't achieve
2. Ability to backup/restore tenants' pools individually

Referring to [the docs](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/v0.80/radosgw/federated-config/), it seems this could possibly be achieved with zones; one zone per tenant and leave out synchronization. Seems a little heavy handed and presumably the overhead is non-negligible.

Is this "supported"? Is there a better way?

I'm running Firefly. I'm also rather new to Ceph so apologies if this is already covered somewhere; kindly send pointers if so...

Answer (score 0):

Since Ceph 10 (Jewel) [RGW multi-tanancy is supported](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/radosgw/multitenancy/). It's purpose clearly covers your first wish: namespace isolation between tenants.

As for the second one, you can't place data of tenants into different pools.